# Angular JS - Pluck on directive attr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to know if there is a way to get all the values of an object in a diretive in Angular JS. For example I have to following array:

```
var example_data = [{ request: 'request1', totalRequests: 100, avgTime: 10 },
{ request: 'request2', totalRequests: 150, avgTime: 13 },
{ request: 'request1', totalRequests: 90, avgTime: 12 },
{ request: 'request2', totalRequests: 50, avgTime: 14 },
{ request: 'request1', totalRequests: 100, avgTime: 13 },
{ request: 'request2', totalRequests: 130, avgTime: 15 }];
```

And I want to extract all request values from the array. 
The problem is I want to do it in directive attr without passing by the controller. Is that any way?
Basically I want some sort of pluck function directly in directive attribute.

**UPDATE**

I have researched and tried the angular-chart.js in fiddle and it worked fine. I found I have to manipulate the data firstly in controller. Now there is just one thing, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SbrKj/197/) the chart is being displayed normally without any anomalyes but in my project it just shows the chart grids and no bar is displayed. What could be the problem here? I already changed the dependencies of angular, chart.js and angular-chart.js to the ones I used in fiddle.

Comment: can you post at least some "pseudo code" for the desired result?

Comment: You mean that you want to pass your array `example_data` as a parameter of your directive ? Like this : `<div my-directive my-parameter="example_data"></div>` ?

Comment: Yes, just like JeanJacques said. I want to pass the value like
   `<div my-directive my-parameter="example_data"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the directive scope like this :

```
angular.module('plunker').directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    resctrict: "A",
    scope: {
      myArray:'='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      console.log(scope.myArray);
    }
  }
});
```

You create your directive scope with `scope: {...}` and you define the binding rule for your scope objects. Here for the myArray declaration, the `'='` means it's a bi-directional binding. [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) are the rules for the scope

And you can use this directive in the view like this :

```
<div my-directive my-array="example_data"></div>
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NYxiC2fpai5przxoBsU4?p=preview) is a plunker with this answer implementation

Comment: I already tried that the reason is that I want to draw a chart with it, and somehow the canvas is not being displayed. I thought that if i tried to assign the attribute directly in the element of DOM was easier but that data I get is not parced correctly for doing that.

Comment: @R.Godinho Can you provide the directive code or reproduce this behavior in a plunker ?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay I got some problems passing the code into fiddle. but here is it: [Link for Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbrKj/196/)